# Errors: How to fix hashes error while updating raspberry pi 3 b

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to update Raspberry Pi 3b through command `sudo apt-get update` but got these "Hashes Errors". I have tried this command several times but the problem still the same. Kindly help me solving this error. Here's thet output after the commmand run:

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]     
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [11.7 MB]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages     
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:11662080 [weak]
   - SHA256:a036d099327c871ba722cea0187061525491c81fe5aaeeb48a545e0de8b36b25
   - SHA1:1ab18738896a891f6b6de1859e629abf0294deba [weak]
   - MD5Sum:fc13d3b6c5064a2bfea645e80e623f2d [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:f00a5626fd1c9e5e450705bb67773463d8c4e7bb2e015478b6366365d69b19fd
   - SHA1:1ecee441f5aaa963901989fde2a20a84f55dc9c1 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:773e014e13e59526b0acbedd9e843b7d [weak]
   - Filesize:2985974 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Sat, 13 Jul 2019 17:56:35 +0000
  Release file created at: Sun, 14 Jul 2019 08:22:08 +0000
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/contrib armhf Packages [56.9 kB]
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/non-free armhf Packages [95.5 kB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/rpi armhf Packages [1,360 B]
0% [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org (93.93.128.133)]                     
Hit:6 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Fetched 85.1 kB in 4min 3s (349 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:11662080 [weak]
    - SHA256:a036d099327c871ba722cea0187061525491c81fe5aaeeb48a545e0de8b36b25
    - SHA1:1ab18738896a891f6b6de1859e629abf0294deba [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fc13d3b6c5064a2bfea645e80e623f2d [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
- SHA256:f00a5626fd1c9e5e450705bb67773463d8c4e7bb2e015478b6366365d69b19fd
    - SHA1:1ecee441f5aaa963901989fde2a20a84f55dc9c1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:773e014e13e59526b0acbedd9e843b7d [weak]
    - Filesize:2985974 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Sat, 13 Jul 2019 17:56:35 +0000
   Release file created at: Sun, 14 Jul 2019 08:22:08 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.***``
```

Comment: on Linux I simply wait day and they repair data on server.

Comment: But I am doing this form 2 days

Comment: And may be because of this issue I can't install tensorflow on raspberry pi

Comment: when I run update Raspberry then it checks only first url. I can see only this url in `/etc/apt/sources.list` If you have more then you can commented this urls which makes problem. Maybe other urls gives update which resolve this problem or you have to wait few days more.

Comment: or maybe find forum on raspberry.org and ask there.

Comment: when I run `sudo apt-get update` then I don't get errors and it check only `Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease`.

Comment: it should cache information somewhere on disk. Maybe if remove cache then it will have to download lists again.

Comment: how to remove cache information from disk ? Can you plz tell me

Comment: As I am beginner to this system and, I dnt know much about this. Kindly help with with this.

Comment: I don't remeber where is cache because usually nobody have to remove it. Better check if you can open in browser raspbian.raspberrypi.org. It can be problem with connection, not problem directly with `apt`, and it can't get all information from internet.

Comment: Raspberry's Forum: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ . They may have better information.

Comment: Ok !!! Thanks for the help

Comment: Improve language and punctuation.